# Is there any way to see the last location with find my iphone before it was wiped?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

I lost my iphone three months ago and it was dead so I could never locate it with the "find my iphone" app. Eventually I gave up and did the wipe feature next time it was turned on. I just got the notification that it was wiped. Is there any way to see where it was in that moment it was turned on and before it was wiped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You are not able to see the last location of a device, only the current location, and since you've removed the device you can't obtain any location information.